# How do I image a external disk with a linux install and restore it to a smaller external disk

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, hard-drive, backup

I have a **bootable** 1T external USB disk but only have a **Linux OS** and few other things on it. It is only used about 50GB. I have another **500GB** external USB disk. I am thinking transfer the state of the 1T disk to the 500GB disk. I tried the **clonezilla** but it requires the destination disk is equal or bigger than the source disk.

How can I migrate the contents of this disk to the smaller disk and still have it bootable?

**EDIT:**

This installed Linux is Fedora, 19 or 20.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com//help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: I changed the software to tools. and I also ask if it is possible to do it without any extra tool/software. Most of time you cannot avoid tools/software to thing in IT area.

Comment: <shrug> All software is a tool to do something. Your edit doesn't really change the question.

Comment: Although @DavidPostill is nitpicking a but here, he is correct, your question should be about how to complete a task or action, not asking for a software recommendation, although a specific software may be given in the answer.

Comment: It is easiest to shrink the partitions prior to moving them. Use Gparted or a similar tool to shrink them to a total of under the destination size, then move them with clonezilla or gparted.

Comment: What flavour of linux? Some of the tools/methods that come to mind may be distro specific?

Comment: @acejavalin, it is a bootable usb disk. if I shrink it with another empty partition, does it still bootable?

Comment: There are several free imaging programs that can restore to a smaller drive: [AOMEI Backupper](http://www.backup-utility.com/disk-clone-software.html) and [Paragon Backup and Recovery](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/br-free/).  Acronis is paid software that can do it.  There may be others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've once migrated a laptop Windows installation on a 500GB HDD to a 250GB SSD and it works. As long as your installation on the bigger disk is smaller than the disk you're migrating to, you might have a chance in shrinking the partition, but at times can be impossible. The issue lies in how the data can be arranged.

You stand a pretty good chance since you're trying to move a 50GB installation to a 500GB disk. Run a defragmentation on the 1TB disk you have first, then use GParted to shrink your partition size to less than 500GB (do like 450GB just to be safe, although you don't have to). Use Clonezilla to copy the image over, then finally increase the partition size to fill up all of the 500GB on your new disk.
Simple GParted tutorial: http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/

(I know this question is about moving a Linux OS, but I believe it should work in a similar fashion.)

Comment: do you know the answer to my this question: http://superuser.com/questions/1034238/gparted-deactivate-will-cause-data-loss-or-not ?

Comment: Ah, no, I'm sorry. I don't know the answer to your question. I'd say, maybe try to resize the partition while booted (i.e. from within Linux) using some tool. I know that's possible within Windows using the OS's own tool. That way your partition will guarantee to be workable. Of course, be sure to defragment first.